# How to fight spam on gmail?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

I have primary email id (like common first name) and I think because of that, I get ton of spam to the point I am thinking of abandoning the id.

Like people share with my their google photos, password rests for different accounts, people sending me pictures, and then the common spam which is a lot too. I am tired of it.

Is there a way I can reduce it through some settings in gmail account? I would rather keep this id because getting another presentable id on gmail is almost impossible too.

I have ton of filters to auto-delete but despite that I get ton of new spam all the time.

Comment: There is a button to mark email as spam; filters is a a feature commonly used for this. If you need further help, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

> Like people share with my their google photos, password rests for different accounts, people sending me pictures

Identifying mails you receive from strangers mistaking you with someone else would require knowledge from your real live. No algorithm can do that, and probably will never be able to do so.

> and then the common spam which is a lot too.

you can play around with Gmail settings, also look for 3rd party tools they might be helpful.
Still if you have very common name, your address might be at the top of the list of spammers and you will receive spam before it's identified by any spam filter.

**So what to do?**

Being in your place I'd probably create another address for mails where my name is not important (automatic mails from bank accounts, service providers, newsletters ...), that would help to reduce the mess.

Experiment with white listing, need to take care that you need to add address to the list before you can receive mail from them.